# Handling complex endpoints in spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I have a complex endpoint that I need to implement in spring boot for a REST service. It looks something like the following:

```
https://[server]:[port]/purchaseManager/api/v1/customers/{customerId}/purchaseOrders
```

A POST to this endpoint would create a new purchase order. The `purchaseOrders` segment must always be preceded by the `customers/{customerId}` segment, but the `customers` segment may stand alone.

How would I write two controllers that interact with each other to handle this endpoint? Since both controllers share much of the same endpoint text, is there something that is better practice than something like the following?

Customers

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/customers")
public class CustomerController {        
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Customer CreateCustomer (@RequestBody String name) {
        return new Customer(name)
    }
}
```

Purchase Orders

```
@RestController
public class PurchaseOrderController {        
    @RequestMapping(value="/customers/{customerId}/purchaseOrders", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public PurchaseOrder CreatePO (@RequestBody String externalId) {
        return new PurchaseOrder(externalId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify an @RequestMapping at class level.
Just do it at method level and it will work.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customers/{customerId}/purchaseOrders", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public PurchaseOrder CreatePO (@RequestBody String externalId, @PathVariable String customerId) {
    return new PurchaseOrder(externalId)
}
```

Comment: The way the code sample was written diverted attention from my intended purpose in asking the question. I realize I can put the request mapping at the method level. My intention is to understand if doing so is the accepted/best way. Apologies for the poor sample. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I've found so far is just to create a separate CustomerLinks class with static fields. This is what Oliver Gierke did in [spring-data-rest sample app](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/payment/web/PaymentController.java):

```
@RequestMapping(value = PaymentLinks.PAYMENT, method = PUT)
```

A class like this can also be helpful when it comes to integration testing -- you don't have api endpoints hardcoded all across your tests.